# Запуск приложения при обнаружении NFC метки

Tags: android, nfc

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть приложение, которое считывает информацию с NFC метки. Необходимо, чтобы даже когда не запущено приложение при обнаружении метки открывалось и выполнялось приложение.

Добавлял в файле манифеста `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />`, приложение запускается при обнаружении метки, но его нельзя запустить с ярлыка (вообще нельзя запустить, только с обнаружением метки)

Вопрос: как можно сделать так, чтобы приложение можно было запустить и с ярлыка и при обнаружении NFC метки

В данный момент файл манифеста такой (без автозапуска):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dns.itnetnfc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="learn2crack.jsonparsing.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
                <action android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity android:name="learn2crack.jsonparsing.WebViewActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="MyBrowser">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="learn2crack.jsonparsing.Browser" />
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Манифест покажите...

Comment: добавил в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно `intent-filter` разделить на два, один для запуска с ярлыка, второй для NFC.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />               
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

И `permission` не место в `intent-filter`, выше есть как `uses-permission` элемент, этого достаточно.

Comment: спасибо большое, это как раз то, что нужно!